# jQuery attr src

Tags: jquery

i've got the following Problem / Question:

I have HTML Code like this:

```
<div id="tab">
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><img src="pic1.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="pic2.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="pic3.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="pic4.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="pic5.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="pic6.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

No i have jQuery and i want to get the img src of a Picture on "click" event. For that i have this code:

```
jQuery('#tab a').click(function() {
alert(jQuery(this).attr('src'));
});
```

But i do not get the code because it has to be

```
jQuery('#tab img')
```

and working with

```
jQuery(this 'a')
```

or something like this is not possible - so what to do?

But i cannot use jQuery('#tab img') because i also need the

Can somebody help?

Thanks a lot.

Greetings,
Sascha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is that `jQuery(this)` in your alert is actually an anchor, and not an image, and thus, it does not have any `src` attribute. Since your anchor contains an image, you'll be able to adjust your code to:

```
jQuery('#tab a').click(function() {
   alert(jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply find the image within the anchor tag you have clicked (i.e. search within the anchor container.)

```
$('#tab a').click(function()
{
   alert($("img", $(this)).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: You can use `$("img", this)`, jQuery can get DOM element as context (second argument), not only jQuery object.